# For $H \le G$ and $N\unlhd G$, prove that $HN$ is the smallest subgroup containing $H$ and $N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

For $H \le G$ and $N\unlhd G$, prove that $HN$ is the smallest subgroup containing $H$ and $N$.

I've already proven it's a subgroup, I just don't know how to prove how its the smallest one.

I know the formula for its order is $|HN| = |H||N|/|H \cap N|.$

Perhaps some counting argument can be made, but im lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue you've already done the hard part! I suspect you're overthinking this.

Here's a hint: Recall elements of $HN$ look like elements $hn$ with $h \in H$ and $n \in N$. Now let $K \leq G$ be *any* subgroup containing $H$ and $N$. We want to to show that $HN \leq K$.

Since $H \leq K$, we know that every $h \in K$. Since $N \leq K$, we know that every $n \in K$ too. Then, since $K$ is a subgroup...

---

I hope this helps ^_^